# Xamarin with Visual Studio : blank screen when debugging

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm making a Xamarin.Forms application with Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 and when I want to debug my app, the application launch but the screen stay white, as loading.

The thing is, I don't have the issue on emulator but my coworker do, and if I launch the app manually after (without the debugger then), it behaves normally.

I already tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, closing and restarting Visual Studio, my device and my laptop, but the problem persist.

I checked with the debugger, and my application does makes the same path on the emulator (and the screen shows) than on the device (where it doesn't)

Do you have any idea ? Thank you !

Comment: Are you doing any IO during the bootstrap process? I would comment-out all IO code and check if your app still hangs.

Comment: I don't do any IO at the start of the application, except an autologging if needed. I removed the app from my phone and tried again (without autologin) but it didn't work. The funny thing is, I have a second app with exactly the same start (same windows and process) for the login/registerging, and there is no problems with it. (Well, there are some, but not about debugging)

Comment: I had same problem like you. In my case, the issue was in translation extension for XAML. Debugger was locked on resourceManager.GetString method. I have the TranslateExtension class from Xamarin localization guideline.

Comment: I do use TranslateExtension. How did you fix this ? By changing the langage of the device ?